# Is LDAP obsolete?

Tags: authentication, ldap

Should I spend time implementing LDAP for authentication in my web application(php)? Is it a 'dead' technology?

If it is what are the alternatives? and, if its not, what are good resources i can use? (books, tutorials)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

LDAP is certainly not a dead technology. In web applications in general, perhaps, but we use LDAP authentication for a good deal of our intranet-based applications. So if you think your application might run inside an office somewhere, LDAP would be appreciated more than likely.

In addition, LDAP makes for a good way of abstracting authentication over lots of different means, Active Directory, Kerberos, even normal SQL-based authentication.

Answer (score 10):

It's certainly not dead. Whether you should implement it in you application depends entirely on you user / customer base and what their needs are.

The new hotness however is federated / claims-based identity. These approaches allow you to completely decouple your authentication from your app. Check out OpenID (used on this site) and SAML.

Comment: Note: OpenID doesn't completely replace LDAP, only the authentication (not authorization part). OAuth provides a universal (cross-platform, distributed) means of requesting permission on a protected resource, however the OAuth provider still needs to perform authorization (ACL) logic. An LDAP directory can be used to store roles associated with a user, which is very helpful.

Comment: In addition, tools like Apache Directory Studio (http://directory.apache.org/studio/) makes it easy to manage entries in an LDAP Directory.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID, such as OAuth/OAuth2 are not independent of LDAP. They are connected with each other. LDAP Servers are the only component that exists without OAuth and OpenID Connect. LDAP Serverss are always the source of users and clients and other entities. LDAP servers have always been used to authenticate users and authorize them for resources. OAuth and OpenID Connect cannot be suported if no LDAP Server is available. OAuth and OpenID Connect are protocols only, not system to manage users.